# What Desktop Environments are supported by Canonical except Unity?

Tags: command-line

I mean exactly **Canonical** supported in Ubuntu, not community-supported.

Comment: unity is not a shell. Could you please clarify your question.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. And answer is relevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Guess you mean "**Canonical** supported", then.

As far as I know, none. But there are some ubuntu flavours that are "recognized" as in "we know they are there and we think they are professionally build enough to mention them on our website and support them with resources (mirrors and stuff)". Some of those use other "shells" - or **window managers** or **desktop environments** as they are called in linux/unix language.

Those are documented on the about pages on ubuntu.com: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours

Some with other desktop environments than "unity" are:

- Ubuntu GNOME — Ubuntu with the GNOME desktop environment
- Kubuntu — Ubuntu with the K Desktop environment
- Lubuntu — Ubuntu that uses LXDE
- Xubuntu — Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop environment
- Ubuntu MATE — Ubuntu with the MATE desktop environment

Comment: None. Wow. Thank you, thats bad news... I really don't like https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962 and can't switch project to anything else with Ubuntu.

Comment: As you can see this bug doesn't just affect Unity (for which Canonical released a fix) but there are many applications and subsystems with the same issue and I doubt that the list is anywhere complete. Maybe you should clarify in your question why you're looking for alternatives.